# What is Intrinsic evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language

I was reading a paper about Deep Learning in Natural Language Processing which uses the phrase "Intrinsic evaluation of word vectors".

What does "Intrinsic evaluation of word vectors" mean?

Comment: Please give a reference to the paper.

Comment: off topic, because its a "LMGTFY" question: http://lmgtfy.com/?iie=1&q=intrinsic+vs+extrinsic+evaluation+of+word+vectors